# Enable/Disable VR from code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

How can I set the display to stereoscopic programmatically in Unity for an app deployed to an Android device?

I want a UI menu where the user can toggle between "VR mode" and normal mode.  I do not want VR mode by default as it should be an option at run-time.  I know there is a setting for "Virtual Reality Supported" in the build settings, but again, I do not want this enabled by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Include `using UnityEngine.XR;` at the top.

Call `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("")` with empty string followed by `XRSettings.enabled = false;` to disable VR in the start function to disable VR.

When you want to enable it later on, call `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("daydream")` with the VR name followed by `XRSettings.enabled = true;`.

You should wait for a frame between each function call. That requires this to be done a corutine function.

Also, On some VR devices, you must go to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Player** and make sure that **Virtual Reality Supported** check-box is **checked**(true) before this will work. Then you can disable it in the Start function and enable it whenever you want.

**EDIT**:

This is known to work on some VR devices and not all VR devices. Although, it should work on Daydream VR.  Complete code sample:

```
IEnumerator LoadDevice(string newDevice, bool enable)
{
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(newDevice);
    yield return null;
    XRSettings.enabled = enable;
}

void EnableVR()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadDevice("daydream", true));
}

void DisableVR()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadDevice("", false));
}
```

Call `EnableVR()` to enable vr and `DisableVR()` to disable it. If you are using anything other than daydream, pass the name of that VR device to the `LoadDevice` function in the `EnableVR()` function.

Comment: I tried that and it did not do anything.  Is there somewhere specific this snippet to enable it must go ?

Comment: Nope. What Unity version are you using?

Comment: This should work for that version. According to Unity, it wont work in the Editor. It will work in Standalone builds. Try it.

Comment: I tried enabling it in Awake() and then logged the value for UnityEngine.VR.VRSettings.enabled  and it was still false.  Like the setting did not take.

Comment: Edited my answer. Take a look at the edit. Also don't try this in the Editor. Try it for a build and it should work. This works here as I am typing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109486/discussion-between-programmer-and-sofia-clover).

Comment: You know I actually can not get that to work, @Programmer.  (I have an unusual app that can launch either as an ordinary app, or, as the VR app.  I'll probably have to split it in two.)  For me this is on Oculus.

Comment: Hi Joe, long time.....This didn't work for you? Try ` VRSettings.loadedDevice = VRDeviceType.None;`. Also try `VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName ("");` and let me know. Let me know

Comment: @JoeBlow Did you try that? I want to know if this works or not

Comment: long time ... you're right it's been like 10 days which is 5 years in software years!!  :)  hang on I will try that tomorrow 4 sure ........ sorry didn't see your msg here ...

Comment: @JoeBlow That's fine. Take your time. I just wanted to make sure you saw my message.

Answer (score 7):

For newer builds of Unity (e.g. 2019.4.0f1) you can use the [XR Plugin Management](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.management@3.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Management.html) package.

To enable call:

```
XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoader();
```

To disable call:

```
XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
```

Comment: Finally the correct answer. Thank you for this. Here is the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.management@3.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings.html

Comment: And for anyone facing the same problem, you need to include this line first: using UnityEngine.XR.Management;

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Unity 2021 but this probably works in earlier versions, I'm also using XR Plug-in Management.

Start:
`XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();`

Stop:
`XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StopSubsystems();`

Full documentation at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.management@4.0/manual/EndUser.html

Answer (score 0):

2020.3.14f1

Doesn't work for me, I get this error when running my Android app.

> Call to DeinitializeLoader without an initialized manager.Please make
> sure wait for initialization to complete before calling this API.

```
[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterAssembliesLoaded)]
        static void TryToDeinitializeOculusLoader()
        {
            XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
        }
```

More context.
I try to unload the Oculus loader, before he manages to load the plugin.
I have an Android app, and the Oculus loader calls `Application.Quit` because the device is not an Oculus headset.
Waiting for `XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.isInitializationComplete` takes too long.
Tried all `RuntimeInitializeLoadType` annotations.

OculusLoader.cs

```
    #elif (UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR)
        [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterAssembliesLoaded)]
        static void RuntimeLoadOVRPlugin()
        {
            var supported = IsDeviceSupported();

            if (supported == DeviceSupportedResult.ExitApplication)
            {
                Debug.LogError("\n\nExiting application:\n\nThis .apk was built with the Oculus XR Plugin loader enabled, but is attempting to run on a non-Oculus device.\nTo build for general Android devices, please disable the Oculus XR Plugin before building the Android player.\n\n\n");
                Application.Quit();
            }

            if (supported != DeviceSupportedResult.Supported)
                return;

            try
            {
                if (!NativeMethods.LoadOVRPlugin(""))
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to load libOVRPlugin.so");
            }
            catch
            {
                // handle Android standalone build with Oculus XR Plugin installed but disabled in loader list.
            }

        }
#endif
```

SOLUTION

Made my build class extend IPreprocessBuildWithReport

```
public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
{
    DisableXRLoaders(report);
}

///https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.management@3.2/manual/EndUser.html
/// Do this as a setup step before you start a build, because the first thing that XR Plug-in Manager does at build time
/// is to serialize the loader list to the build target.

void DisableXRLoaders(BuildReport report)
{
    
    XRGeneralSettingsPerBuildTarget buildTargetSettings;
    EditorBuildSettings.TryGetConfigObject(XRGeneralSettings.k_SettingsKey, out buildTargetSettings);
    if (buildTargetSettings == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    XRGeneralSettings settings = buildTargetSettings.SettingsForBuildTarget(report.summary.platformGroup);
    if (settings == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    XRManagerSettings loaderManager = settings.AssignedSettings;
    
    if (loaderManager == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    var loaders = loaderManager.activeLoaders;
    
    // If there are no loaders present in the current manager instance, then the settings will not be included in the current build.
    if (loaders.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var loadersForRemoval = new List<XRLoader>();
    
    loadersForRemoval.AddRange(loaders);
    
    foreach (var loader in loadersForRemoval)
    {
        loaderManager.TryRemoveLoader(loader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void Awake() {
          StartCoroutine(SwitchToVR(()=>{
                Debug.Log("Switched to VR Mode");
          }));

          //For disable VR Mode
          XRSettings.enabled = false;
  }
 
  IEnumerator SwitchToVR(Action callback) {
            // Device names are lowercase, as returned by `XRSettings.supportedDevices`.
            // Google original, makes you specify
            // string desiredDevice = "daydream"; // Or "cardboard".
            // XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(desiredDevice);
            // this is slightly better;
            
            string[] Devices = new string[] { "daydream", "cardboard" };
             XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(Devices);
      
            // Must wait one frame after calling `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName()`.
            yield return null;
          
            // Now it's ok to enable VR mode.
            XRSettings.enabled = true;
            callback.Invoke();
   }
```