# Disable/Enable VR from code using SteamVR 2.0.1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, steamvr

As the title says, I'm trying to enable/disable VR between different applications, and I need to do it as many times as I want.
I'm using Unity 2017.4 and SteamVR 2.0.1. I'm trying to do it with two different scenes of the same project (testing one in the editor, and launching the other as .exe).

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702228/enable-disable-vr-from-code) is not working, since apparently Actions and Poses are not handled correctly when VR is stopped with XRSettings.enabled = false.

Did anyone experienced the same behaviour?

I tried to find a workaround:

**1)** Disabling/enabling also Player and Hands

```
    ...
    // ** ENABLE VR **
    if (enable)
    {
        print("Enabling VR ...");

        XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("OpenVR");
        yield return null;

        print("Loaded device: " + XRSettings.loadedDeviceName);
        XRSettings.enabled = enable;
        EnablePlayerAndHands(true);
    }
    // ** DISABLE VR **
    else
    {
        print("Disabling VR ...");

        EnablePlayerAndHands(false);
        XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("");
        yield return null;

        print("Loaded device: " + XRSettings.loadedDeviceName);
        XRSettings.enabled = false;
    }
    ...
```

**2)** Added these lines in the SteamVR.cs file:

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ...

        // added code
        SteamVR_Input.initialized = false;
        SteamVR_Behaviour.instance = null;
    }
```

(In order to make it work, I had to add a public setter for the SteamVR_Behaviour.instance property).

**3)** In SteamVR_Behaviour, I added a check inside Update(), LateUpdate() and FixedUpdate():

```
if (_instance != null) ... // do update
```

---

These modifications won't fix the problems actually, because I still have some exceptions when I enable back VR, for example:

```
GetPoseActionData error (/actions/default/in/SkeletonLeftHand): InvalidHandle handle: 1152990670760182193
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Action_Pose:UpdateValue(SteamVR_Input_Sources, Boolean) (at Assets/SteamVR/Input/SteamVR_Action_Pose.cs:96)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Action_Skeleton:UpdateValue(SteamVR_Input_Sources, Boolean) (at Assets/SteamVR/Input/SteamVR_Action_Skeleton.cs:75)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Input:UpdateSkeletonActions(SteamVR_Input_Sources, Boolean) (at Assets/SteamVR/Input/SteamVR_Input.cs:487)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Input:UpdateSkeletonActions(Boolean) (at Assets/SteamVR/Input/SteamVR_Input.cs:462)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Input:LateUpdate() (at Assets/SteamVR/Input/SteamVR_Input.cs:352)
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Behaviour:LateUpdate() (at Assets/SteamVR/Scripts/SteamVR_Behaviour.cs:224)
```

...but they are raised just a few times and then they stop. It could be due to some bad timing. Btw, I put an Interactable gameobject inside the empty scene just to test if I could still interact with it after disabling/enabling, and it seems that I can.

Still, I would expect some easier and cleaner method to achieve my goal. Am I missing something obvious or is it a bug from SteamVR newest version?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For the sake of completion, a possible solution has been discussed: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamvr_unity_plugin/issues/307

Answer (score -1):

Please see this link for reference

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings-enabled.html

Stopping a VR session is not supported in GearVR, not sure about SteamVR

Comment: Hi zambari,
I'm sorry, what do you mean is not supported? By Unity or by SteamVR?

Comment: my original answer was paritally wrong, please see the udpated answer